2D Canvas JavaScript | How do I draw a circle in canvas that is set to a defined number of degrees?
I simulate an interactive view for a player. As long as a component of the game is within the view width, it should be possible to interact with it. With my code, it is not a problem to play the different directions, but only in 180°. Can I limit the view further so that it is a variable number, as you can see here in my sketch?
Blue is the player's collision area.
Red is the current view width.
Gray is the desired view width.
https://i.imgur.com/cyNYpv3.png
Interact with the canvas in focusing the window and change direction with WASD or arrow keys.


const canvas = document.querySelector('canvas')
const context = canvas.getContext('2d');

canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
canvas.width = window.innerWidth;

const keymap = [];

const player = { 
  x: window.innerWidth / 2 - 50, 
  y: window.innerHeight / 2 - 50,
  size: 100,
  range: 200,
  view: {
    start: 0,
    end: Math.PI
  }
};

const draw = () => {
  context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  
  context.fillStyle = 'rgba(0, 0, 255, .6)';
  context.fillRect(
    player.x,
    player.y,
    player.size, 
    player.size, 
  );
  
  context.fillStyle = 'rgba(0, 0, 0, .6)';
  context.beginPath();
  context.arc(
    player.x + player.size / 2, 
    player.y + player.size / 2, 
    player.range, 
    player.view.start, 
    player.view.end, 
    false
  );
  context.fill();
};

const change = () => {
  let tempChange = { x: 0, y: 0 };
  
  keymap.forEach(direction => {
    if (direction === 'KeyS' || direction === 'ArrowDown') {
      tempChange.y = 1;
    }

    if (direction === 'KeyA' || direction === 'ArrowLeft') {
      tempChange.x = -1;
    }

    if (direction === 'KeyW' || direction === 'ArrowUp') {
      tempChange.y = -1;
    }

    if (direction === 'KeyD' || direction === 'ArrowRight') {
      tempChange.x = 1;
    }
  });
  
  const actions = {
    '1_1': () => {
      // Down Right
      player.view.start = 1.75 * Math.PI;
      player.view.end = 0.75 * Math.PI;
    },
    '1_-1': () => {
      // Up Right
      player.view.start = 1.25 * Math.PI;
      player.view.end = 0.25 * Math.PI;
    },
    '1_0': () => {
      // Right
      player.view.start = 1.5 * Math.PI;
      player.view.end = 0.5 * Math.PI;
    },
    '-1_1': () => {
      // Down Left
      player.view.start = 0.25 * Math.PI;
      player.view.end = 1.25 * Math.PI;
    },
    '-1_-1': () => {
      // Up Left
      player.view.start = 0.75 * Math.PI;
      player.view.end = 1.75 * Math.PI;
    },
    '-1_0': () => {
      // Left
      player.view.start = 0.5 * Math.PI;
      player.view.end = 1.5 * Math.PI;
    },
    '0_1': () => {
      // Down
      player.view.start = 0;
      player.view.end = Math.PI;
    },
    '0_-1': () => {
      // Up
      player.view.start = Math.PI;
      player.view.end = 0;
    },
    '0_0': () => {},
  };

  const dir = tempChange.x + '_' + tempChange.y;
  const func = actions[dir];
  func();
};

const loop = () => {
  change();
  draw();
  
  requestAnimationFrame(loop);
};

const setup = () => {
  window.addEventListener('keydown', event => {
    const key = event.code;
    const index = keymap.indexOf(key);

    if (index > -1)
      keymap.splice(index, 1);

    keymap.push(key);
  });

  window.addEventListener('keyup', event => {
    const key = event.code;
    const index = keymap.indexOf(key);

    if (index > -1)
      keymap.splice(index, 1);
  });
};

setup();
requestAnimationFrame(loop);
<canvas></canvas>




It looks like you have the view field declared in radians from 0 to pi (180°) changing that to your desired radians could fix it

Can you please share a solution for a direction? It seems like the "circle" is moving out of position if I mix up some values.

Two things:

The .arc command will only draw the part of the FOV that follows a circle. When you fill that, it will "connect" the start and end of that path. To make sure your FOV looks like a slice of pie, you have to ensure there's a point added to the path that goes to the center of the player. See context.lineTo after context.arc
It's easier to manage variable field-of-view if you store just the orientation of the player + the FOV angle. I updated your key-handler to write player.orientation. 0 means pointing right, and then it spans 2PI clockwise. In draw, I subtract/add half the FOV from the orientation to get to the arc's start and end angle.



const canvas = document.querySelector('canvas')
const context = canvas.getContext('2d');

canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
canvas.width = window.innerWidth;

const keymap = [];

const player = { 
  x: window.innerWidth / 2 - 50, 
  y: window.innerHeight / 2 - 50,
  size: 100,
  range: 200,
  orientation: 0,
  fov: 140 * (Math.PI / 180)
};

const draw = () => {
  context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  
  context.fillStyle = 'rgba(0, 0, 255, .6)';
  context.fillRect(
    player.x,
    player.y,
    player.size, 
    player.size, 
  );
  
  const viewStart = player.orientation - player.fov / 2;
  const viewEnd = player.orientation + player.fov / 2;
  const ax = player.x + player.size / 2;
  const ay = player.y + player.size / 2;
  context.fillStyle = 'rgba(0, 0, 0, .6)';
  context.beginPath();
  context.arc(
    ax, 
    ay, 
    player.range, 
    viewStart, 
    viewEnd,
    false
  );
  
  context.lineTo(ax, ay)
  
  context.fill();
};

const change = () => {

  const tempChange = { x: 0, y: 0 }
  
  keymap.forEach(direction => {
    if (direction === 'KeyS' || direction === 'ArrowDown') {
      tempChange.y = 1;
    }

    if (direction === 'KeyA' || direction === 'ArrowLeft') {
      tempChange.x = -1;
    }

    if (direction === 'KeyW' || direction === 'ArrowUp') {
      tempChange.y = -1;
    }

    if (direction === 'KeyD' || direction === 'ArrowRight') {
      tempChange.x = 1;
    }
  });
  
  const actions = {
   '1_0': () => {
      // Right
      player.orientation = 0;
    },
    '1_1': () => {
      // Down Right
      player.orientation = 0.25 * Math.PI;
    },
    '0_1': () => {
      // Down
      player.orientation = 0.5 * Math.PI;
    },
    '-1_1': () => {
      // Down Left
      player.orientation = 0.75 * Math.PI;
    },
    '-1_0': () => {
      // Left
      player.orientation = 1 * Math.PI;
    },
    '-1_-1': () => {
      // Up Left
      player.orientation = 1.25 * Math.PI;
    },
    '0_-1': () => {
      // Up
      player.orientation = 1.5 * Math.PI;
    },

    '1_-1': () => {
      // Up Right
      player.orientation = 1.75 * Math.PI;
    },

    '0_0': () => {},
  };

  const dir = tempChange.x + '_' + tempChange.y;
  const func = actions[dir];
  func();
};

const loop = () => {
  change();
  draw();
  
  requestAnimationFrame(loop);
};

const setup = () => {
  window.addEventListener('keydown', event => {
    const key = event.code;
    const index = keymap.indexOf(key);

    if (index > -1)
      keymap.splice(index, 1);

    keymap.push(key);
    
    event.preventDefault();
  });

  window.addEventListener('keyup', event => {
    const key = event.code;
    const index = keymap.indexOf(key);

    if (index > -1)
      keymap.splice(index, 1);
  });
};

setup();
requestAnimationFrame(loop);
<canvas></canvas>



